# Get field value in modal list item display dialog on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, modal-dialog

I have a basic custom list with items that open in a modal display form. I need to get the value of one of the fields, store it in a javascript variable, and further process it. How do I get the field value?

Comment: If you have the item ID, you can query it using the rest api to get field values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want get field value on item Display Form. Then you achieve this using [SPUtility.js](https://sputility.codeplex.com/)

Steps:

1. Edit view item form in SharePoint UI.
2. Add Script editor web part.
3. Give reference of "sputitly.js" and jquery.min.js

   ```
   <script src="/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/sputility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
4. Add the following script in script tag.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
   var fldValue= SPUtility.GetSPField('Your Column Name').GetValue();
   });
   </script>
   ```
5. Ok & Save the page.

"Your field value will be stored in "fldValue" javascript variable."

SPUtility.js is a JavaScript library used to make modifications to SharePoint's list forms (NewForm.aspx, DispForm and EditForm.aspx in a survey, custom list or library). It works with SharePoint 2007, 2010, and 2013 (including SharePoint Online / Office 365).

[SPUtility.js Documentation](https://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Common%20SPField%20functions)

Comment: Thanks. Also just wanted to point out that `.GetValue()` needs to be appended at the end like so: `fldValue= SPUtility.GetSPField('Your Column Name').GetValue()`